# SQL: Match unencrypted value with encrypted value

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have a table like this:**

```
-------------------------------------
| id   | name                       |
-------------------------------------
| 1    | butter                     |
| 2    | cheese                     |
| 3    | steak                      |
-------------------------------------
```

**The encrypted version of these values are:**

```
SELECT id, ENCRYPT(`name`, 'thisismycoolsalt') FROM `table`

-------------------------------------
| id   | name                       |
-------------------------------------
| 1    | 74684a4e6b6d564b526e76674d |
| 2    | 74686e5a7379506554564b3451 |
| 3    | 74687341565776786a55704359 |
-------------------------------------
```

My question is, if I have the encrypted version of the name, how can I select the row with the unencrypted form?

I am trying to do this, but this is the improper syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE ENCRYPT(`name`, 'thisismycoolsalt')='74684a4e6b6d564b526e76674d'
```

Comment: Now that's my kind of table

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work, as can be seen here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da7bc4/10

Version with a `JOIN` clause :

```
SELECT
  plain.id, plain.name,
  encrypted.id AS e_id, encrypted.name AS e_name
FROM encrypted
INNER JOIN plain ON ENCRYPT(plain.name, encrypted.salt) = encrypted.name;
```

Version with a simple `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM plain
WHERE ENCRYPT(name, 'thisismycoolsalt') = 'thsAVWvxjUpCY'
```

The data :

```
Plain table :

ID  NAME
1   butter
2   cheese
3   steak

Encrypted table :

ID  NAME            SALT
1   thJNkmVKRnvgM   thisismycoolsalt
2   thnZsyPeTVK4Q   thisismycoolsalt
3   thsAVWvxjUpCY   thisismycoolsalt
```

Maybe you could post the syntax error you are getting if you want more help.